# Custom login page with redirect

Tags: users, forms

I've set up a custom login page witht the difference that that one should redirect the user to another page.

I use the default drupal login form so I dont really now how to fix the form alter for my custom form without it to change the default login form too.

What could I do to fix this?

My code:

```
function mymodule_cv_login() {
    // Print the user login form
    $form = drupal_get_form('user_login');

    $form['redirect'] = 'cv';

    return $form;
}

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
        $path = 'profil';
        $form['#action'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => array('destination' => $path)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what page you are on by looking at $_GET['q'] (or using the arg() function) so you could base your alter on that.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the Login Destination module http://drupal.org/project/login_destination which I will probably handle the cases you want to cover as well.

Comment: I used rules before, but each login page has to have a different look. Thats why I wanted a seperate login.